Compiling b4a application for other mobile cpu architucture
Recently i start learning android programming with B4A and now i am a beginner in android programming.
My question is:
How to compile B4A application for other mobile cpu architecture?
For example : compiling B4a application for ARMv7-A or x86_64 mobile cpu architecture.
I could not find the awnser on B4X website
